# Jolt concatenate only if my two columns are not Null, default value if it is NULL

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a JSON .
Requirement is to concatenate only if my two columns are not Null, default value if any of one column is NULL

**Input 1** :

```json
[
  {
    "division_Code": "F",
    "department_Code": "L3D4",
    "department": "BABY ACCESSORIES"
  }
]
```

**Output Expected** :

```json
{
  "PLMDepartment" : "FL3D4"
}
```

**Input 2** :

```json
[
  {
    "division_Code": "",
    "department_Code": "L3D4",
    "department": "BABY ACCESSORIES"
  }
]
```

**Output Expected** :

```json
{
  "PLMDepartment" : "Invalid"
}
```

**Input 3** :

```json
[
  {
    "division_Code": "F",
    "department_Code": "",
    "department": "BABY ACCESSORIES"
  }
]
```

**Output Expected** :

```json
{
  "PLMDepartment" : "Invalid"
}
```

**Jolt spec** I tried :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PLMDepartment": "=concat(@(1,division_Code),@(1,department_Code))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PLMDepartment": "PLMDepartment"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But its not coming as expected.

Pls help Can anyone who is a jolt expert, help me get the desired output. I think i m stuck in the last step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditionally return the desired result after determining whether one of those attributes has zero size such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "szDvC": "=size(@(1,division_Code))",
        "szDpC": "=size(@(1,department_Code))",
        "Div1": "=divide(@(1,szDpC),@(1,szDvC))",
        "Div2": "=divide(@(1,szDvC),@(1,szDpC))",
        "PLMDepartment": "=concat(@(1,division_Code),@(1,department_Code))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Div*": {
          "0.0": {
            "#Invalid": "PLMDepartment"
          },
          "*": {
            "@2,PLMDepartment": "PLMDepartment"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one component among repeated ones if "PLMDepartment" is an array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below spec can do the trick with less number of functions.

```
        [{
        "operation": "modify-default-beta",
        "spec": {
        "*": {
            "PLMDepartment": "=concat(@(1,division_Code),@(1,department_Code))"
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
        "*": {
            "division_Code": {
            "": {
                "#Invalid": "PLMDepartment"
            },
            "*": {
                "@2,department_Code": {
                "": {
                    "#Invalid": "PLMDepartment"
                },
                "*": {
                    "@4,PLMDepartment": "PLMDepartment"
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    ]
```

[image]